# Git, set up .gitignore to ignore all files EXCEPT .conf files, including subdirectories too

Tags: git, gitignore

How to get Git to ignore all files in a directory and **ALSO** in its subdirectories except for .conf files?

Currently I have this in my .gitignore:

```
!/some/dir/
/some/dir/*
!/some/dir/**/
!/some/dir/**/*.conf
```

So, I want to ignore all files in /some/dir/ and also its subdirectories, except for *.conf files.

But it is not ignoring any file in /some/dir/.

For example, /some/dir/somefile is not ignore, /some/dir/subdir/anotherfile is not ignore also. I just want to not ignore files like: /some/dir/subdir/file.conf.

Comment: If the file is not having any apparent effect *at all*, you've almost certainly got encoding trouble. save it as utf-8 or ascii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to tweak this in various ways, but here's the simplest thing I know of that meets your stated requirements.  Create a `.gitignore` file inside `some/dir` that reads:

```
*
!*/
!*.conf
```

and you're all set.

Here is an example:

```
$ mkdir test-ignore
$ cd test-ignore
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test ignore rules > README
$ git add README 
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 33962fc] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ mkdir -p some/dir/a some/dir/b
$ touch some/dir/file some/dir/a/a.conf some/dir/b/b.conf some/dir/a/ignored
$ cat > some/dir/.gitignore << END
> *
> !*/
> !*.conf
> END
$ git add .
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   some/dir/a/a.conf
        new file:   some/dir/b/b.conf

$
```

#### Explanation

- `*` means *ignore everything* (that is currently untracked, of course; tracked files cannot be ignored).
- `!*/` means *if it's a directory, don't ignore it, do search it*, and being later in the file, this overrides a previous entry; of course, being searched does not make *files* in the directory get added, but the subdirectory does get scanned;
- `!*.conf` means *if a file's base name matches `*.conf`, don't ignore it*, so any files in `some/dir` named that are named `*.conf`, or any files in any subdirectory  of `some/dir` that are named `*.conf`, are not-ignored and hence get added.

That's why `some/dir/a/a.conf` did get added, but `some/dir/a/ignored` did not.

(You didn't specify in text what you want to do with `some/dir/somefile` and `some/dir/thing.conf` so I had the same rules apply here: `file` is ignored and `thing.conf` is not-ignored.  I think that's what you intended with `!**/*.conf`.)

In general, moving a `.gitignore` file "down the tree" as far as it goes will simplify it, so it's easier to put this in `some/dir/.gitignore`.  The general rule `!*/`, close enough to the end of a `.gitignore`, forces Git not to short-circuit the scanning of subdirectories found recursively.  Other than these two rules (which *should* be obvious, but aren't always obvious at first), the rest is obvious.